# Helm install tarantool-operator 0.0.10 problem: 404 not found

Tags: kubernetes-helm, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I'm trying to install tarantool-operator according to the official documentation "Tarantool Cartridge on Kubernetes": https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/latest/book/cartridge/cartridge_kubernetes_guide/#using-minikube

Execute command:

```
minikube start --memory 4096
helm repo add tarantool https://tarantool.github.io/tarantool-operator
helm search repo tarantool
```

Result:

```
NAME                            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
tarantool/tarantool-operator    0.0.10          1.16.0          kubernetes tarantool operator
tarantool/cartridge             0.0.10          1.0             A Helm chart for tarantool
```

Then I do:

```
helm install tarantool-operator tarantool/tarantool-operator --namespace tarantool --create-namespace --version 0.0.10
```

I get an error 404:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to fetch https://tarantool.github.io/tarantool-operator/releases/download/tarantool-operator-0.0.10/tarantool-operator-0.0.10.tgz : 404 Not Found
```

Where am I wrong?

P.S. minikube version 1.27.0 on Windows 10 (Hyper-V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tarantool-operator-0.0.10.tgz is not available for download(

You can build it from source using

```
make docker-build
make push-to-minikube
```

accoriding to the docs

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue.

So, you may handle it temporary by youself overriding helm chart from local file.

Created simple fix - see [merge request](https://github.com/tarantool/helm-charts/pull/19).
Waiting for maintainers to merge it.

See changes need to be made [here](https://github.com/tarantool/helm-charts/pull/19/commits/865cfdc3fdf3449da89a13cab0173a990b156bdb).